# Span manipulation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please explain the term "span manipulation: in jQuery and give a small example?

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving an example for span manipulation

```
   <span class="test">hello world</span>

$('.test').click(function() {
$(this).text("Rajasekhar"); // this will update hello world to rajasekhar
});

$('.test').text(); // gives you hello world
```

Comment: rajasekhar is this what you are looking